# Convert mp4 sound to text in python

Tags: python, audio, wav, mp4

I want to convert a sound recording from Facebook Messenger to text. 
Here is an example of an .mp4 file send using Facebook's API:
https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.3654-21/15720510_10211855778255994_5430581267814940672_n.mp4/audioclip-1484407992000-3392.mp4?oh=a78286aa96c9dea29e5d07854194801c&oe=587C3833

So this file includes only audio (not video) and I want to convert it to text.

Moreover, I want to do it as fast as possible since I'll use the generated text in an almost real-time application (i.e. user sends the .mp4 file, the script translates it to text and shows it back).

I've found this example https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/audio_transcribe.py
and here is the code I use:

```
import requests
import speech_recognition as sr

url = 'https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.3654-21/15720510_10211855778255994_5430581267814940672_n.mp4/audioclip-1484407992000-3392.mp4?oh=a78286aa96c9dea29e5d07854194801c&oe=587C3833'
r = requests.get(url)

with open("test.mp4", "wb") as handle:
    for data in r.iter_content():
        handle.write(data)

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile('test.mp4') as source:
    audio = r.record(source)

command = r.recognize_google(audio)
print command
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Asterios\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 200, in __enter__
    self.audio_reader = aifc.open(aiff_file, "rb")
  File "C:\Users\Asterios\Anaconda2\lib\aifc.py", line 952, in open
    return Aifc_read(f)
  File "C:\Users\Asterios\Anaconda2\lib\aifc.py", line 347, in __init__
    self.initfp(f)
  File "C:\Users\Asterios\Anaconda2\lib\aifc.py", line 298, in initfp
    chunk = Chunk(file)
  File "C:\Users\Asterios\Anaconda2\lib\chunk.py", line 63, in __init__
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I want to run the script on the free-plan of pythonanywhere.com, so I'm not sure how I can install tools like ffmpeg there.

EDIT 2: If you run the above script substituting the url with this one "http://www.wavsource.com/snds_2017-01-08_2348563217987237/people/men/about_time.wav" and change 'mp4' to 'wav', the it works fine. So it is for sure something with the file format.

Comment: can you play test.wav with audio/video player?

Comment: Yeap. You can run the code and here the sound.

Comment: you are reading an mp4 file as wav format, check that out & convert your mp4 to wav

Comment: I tried but I cannot find out how to do it properly.

Comment: @Stergios WAV format contains uncompressed digital sound (called PCM). Now MP4 file will contain **compressed** AAC data its not even sound, just maths, but needs to be decoded into PCM audio. Use a tool like FFmpeg to convert. There are many **using FFmpeg with Python** tutorials online...

Comment: I've changed the code above so that I save the downloaded file as mp4 (instead of wav).

Comment: @Stergios Changing the extension / filename is not enough, you need to **convert** the mp4 file to wav file as VC.One mentioned.

Comment: I can't work out which line in your code is generating that error... The traceback doesn't include any lines from your code, unless it is the line `  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>` in which case it is the import of requests that causes the problem. I don't think that is correct though.

Comment: However, I'd recommend looking at the place where the error is generated. It only gives `EOFError` because the code says `raise EOFError`. That is probably in an `except:` block, so have a look at the `try:` block preceding it to see what goes wrong. FYI an [EOFError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) is "Raised when one of the built-in functions (input() or raw_input()) hits an end-of-file condition (EOF) without reading any data. (N.B.: the file.read() and file.readline() methods return an empty string when they hit EOF.)

Comment: The error comes from the 'audio = r.record(source)' line.
The EOFError is not within a try block. It is within an 'if' (without else clause).

Comment: I made and edit (EDIT 2) and showed that the code works perfectly with a WAV file. So The question is how I convert the MP4 to a valid WAV format.

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but looks possible with audiotools: audiotools.MP3Audio.from_pcm("track.mp4",audiotools.open("track.wav").to_pcm())

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally I found an solution. I'm posting it here in case it helps someone in the future.

Fortunately, pythonanywhere.com comes with avconv pre-installed (avconv is similar to ffmpeg).

So here is some code that works:

```
import urllib2
import speech_recognition as sr
import subprocess
import os

url = 'https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.3654-21/15720510_10211855778255994_5430581267814940672_n.mp4/audioclip-1484407992000-3392.mp4?oh=a78286aa96c9dea29e5d07854194801c&oe=587C3833'
mp4file = urllib2.urlopen(url)

with open("test.mp4", "wb") as handle:
    handle.write(mp4file.read())

cmdline = ['avconv',
           '-i',
           'test.mp4',
           '-vn',
           '-f',
           'wav',
           'test.wav']
subprocess.call(cmdline)

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile('test.wav') as source:
    audio = r.record(source)

command = r.recognize_google(audio)
print command

os.remove("test.mp4")
os.remove("test.wav")
```

In the free plan, `cdn.fbsbx.com` was not on the white list of sites on pythonanywhere so I could not download the content with `urllib2`. I contacted them and they added the domain to the white list within 1-2 hours!

So a huge thanks and congrats to them for the excellent service even though I'm using the free tier.

Answer (score 1):

Use Python Video Converter
https://github.com/senko/python-video-converter

```
import requests
import speech_recognition as sr
from converter import Converter

url = 'https://cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.3654-21/15720510_10211855778255994_5430581267814940672_n.mp4/audioclip-1484407992000-3392.mp4?oh=a78286aa96c9dea29e5d07854194801c&oe=587C3833'
r = requests.get(url)
c = Converter()

with open("/tmp/test.mp4", "wb") as handle:
for data in r.iter_content():
handle.write(data)

conv = c.convert('/tmp/test.mp4', '/tmp/test.wav', {
    'format': 'wav',
    'audio': {
    'codec': 'pcm',
    'samplerate': 44100,
    'channels': 2
    },
})

for timecode in conv:
    pass

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile('/tmp/test.wav') as source:
audio = r.record(source)

command = r.recognize_google(audio)
print command
```

Comment: Thanks but this is still based on FFmpeg. As I mention on my original post, I want to run the script on the free-plan of pythonanywhere.com, so I'm not sure if/how I can install tools like ffmpeg there.

Comment: Well,, after some contemplation, here's the relevant raw c++ source from the most recent ffmpeg snapshot:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6FklHUATePWaURLSEE3N0xuZms/view?usp=sharing  These are encoding and decoding libraries for wav pcm and mp4 aac.  Grab all the bitwise math from there you can.  I hope this assists in some way to write your own routine.  It would be "hack"-tastic, but its the fastest way to get it done.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can build something out of that.

Comment: @RobertSmith I like to try your approach. Where is the text file saved?