# conversion of mp4 file into text using python in windows

Tags: python, wav, pyffmpeg

I want to convert the mp4 file in my system into text using python its easy to convert wav file into text but mp4 file conversion is having many issues especially with ffmpeg i think. In my code it always shows no such file or directory is found

enter code here

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os    
import pyaudio  

command2mp3 = 'ffmpeg -i nanavi.mp4 nanavi.mp3'    
command2wav = 'ffmpeg -i nanavi.mp3 nanavi.wav'   

os.system(command2mp3)    
os.system(command2wav)  

r = sr.Recognizer()   

with sr.AudioFile("nanavi.wav") as source:    
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)    
    audio = r.listen(source, duration=10)    
print(r.recognize_google(audio))
```

**error**
FileNotFoundError:

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nanavi.wav

Comment: Does this answer you question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525200/convert-mp4-sound-to-text-in-python  and be sure to double check whether the wav file is in the same directory or not!

Comment: @FareedKhan there is no wav file i want to convert mp4 into one